# Appending word at the end of line with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a code block as follows in a file:

```
BalancerMember http://snode1:80 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_snode1
BalancerMember http://snode2:80 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_snode2
```

I want to search for all lines which had `tc_` keyword and add `status=D` at the end of those lines. So, the above entries will become like this

```
BalancerMember http://snode1:80 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_snode1 status=D
BalancerMember http://snode2:80 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1  timeout=30 keepalive=on route=tc_snode2 status=D
```

I am using the following command to achieve this:

```sh
sed -i '/tc_/a status=D' app.conf
```

But I can see `status=D` is being after a newline. I don't want a newline for this. It should be appended with a '' (space) .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try

```
sed  -e '/tc_/s/$/ status=D/'
```

where

- `/tc_/` on line where tc_ is found,
- `s` substitute,
- `/$` end of line,
- `/ status=D/` by this string

if it looks OK, add `-i` to edit in place.