# insert text at specific position with grep or vim

Tags: grep, vim, nagios

I need to insert text at specific position but the line can be anywhere because file is huge 1000 to 2000 lines and information is added in middle or anywhere.

A short version of example below:

```
 1 define service{
 2         service_description             version-check-aix
 3         use                             passive-service
 4         max_check_attempts              1
 5         initial_state                   o
 6         notifications_enabled           0
 7         host_name                       hosts1,host2
 8 }
 9
10 define service{
11         service_description             version-check-unix
12         use                             passive-service
13         max_check_attempts              1
14         notifications_enabled           0
15         host_name                       hosts1,host2
16 }
17 define service{
18         service_description             version-check-linux
19         use                             passive-service
20         initial_state                   o
21         notifications_enabled           0
22         host_name                       hosts1,host2
```

I need to append host3 at end of line which contains `host_name<tab><something here>,host3`. In my example that would be on line 15. (The line numbers are for illustration and are not present in the data file.)

Can i do `grep -in version-check-unix` and insert "host3"? How?

Comment: Please detail what needs to be inserted (always the same, or does it differ) depending on what condition (only on line 15, or whenever ... happens).

Comment: `grep` can only extract, not insert.

Comment: You probably want a language that can edit conditionally, like `awk` or `perl`. Please detail the problem and we will help.

Comment: you say "line number 15" but "it can be anywhere" -- so specify as carefully as you can what you want to have happen

Comment: You say that you wish to to append "host3" at end of line which contains "host_name,host3" but line 15 does not have this - please correct the specifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appending word at the end of line with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328652/appending-word-at-the-end-of-line-with-sed)

Answer (score 1):

You wish to append something to a line which matches certain criteria. This can be done with `sed`, among others.

Let us assume that the match criteria are: The line has the string "host_name" and then (after some spaces and/or TABs) "hosts1,host2"; you wish to add ",host3".  Then this would work:

```
cat file | sed 's/\(^[\t ]\+host_name[\t ]\+hosts1,host2$\)/\1,host3/g' > newfile
```

where `file` is the original file and `newfile` the new, edited file.

Comment: Please note that you wrote "hosts1" but "host2", if this is a typo please correct this in the command line.

Comment: thank you i will use this and let you know the result. Yes that was typo mistake