# replacing and adding at the end of lines with one line sed command

Tags: sed

I have a line as follows

```
 // Testing this
```

I am trying to use a sed command to replace the // with a /* (sentence or word in between) */ on each line.

so it should look something like this

```
/* Testing this */
```

The first part is easy with calling

```
sed 's#//#/*#'
```

however, with the second part, I tried this solution

[Appending word at the end of line with sed [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328652/appending-word-at-the-end-of-line-with-sed)

I tried with `-e` which gave me an error of 'unterminated s command'. Then, I tried with a semi colon to make it one so it was something along the lines of

```
's#//#/*#;#//#s#/$#*/#'
```

but all that seems to do is the first part (replacing `//` with `/*`)and not the second (putting a `*/` at the end of the same line).

What am I not doing correctly? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to convert C++-style comments to C-style comments ?

Comment: @don_crissti yes but I want to know in general. I have other files where I have to replace phone numbers and add things to the end of them so I am trying to figure out how to do it in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$ cat testfile
// Testing this
foobar
$ sed 'sx//\(.*\)x/*\1 */x' testfile
/* Testing this */
foobar
$
```

- `sx//` : search for lines containing `//`
- `\(.*\)x` : place the remaining part of the line into capture group 1
- `/*\1 */x` : replace the remaining part of the line with `/*` (start of comment, C-style) followed by the contents of the capture group 1 (referenced as `\1`), followed by `*/` (end of comment, C-style)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
Do you mind me asking, what is the \(.*\) is for in this case? I realize the " \( " and " \) " are escape sequences for the parenthesis, but what are we doing with the " .*  " ?

PS: I don't know why the backslash character is not showing up.

Comment: Sure, elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: make the search and replace conditional on the comment being matched at all:

```
sed '\!//! {s!!/*!; s!$! */!}' file
```

That reads:

- if the line contains the pattern `//`, then

  - replace the matched text with `/*`
  - and then replace the empty string at end of line with `*/`